# How to force Mono ADO.NET record name index to be case insensitive

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, mono, datareader

In Mono 3.2.5, code

```
var Record = GetRecord().First();
Record["Dokumnr"];


public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetRecord() {
            using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection("host=localhost;user=me"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                DbCommand command = (DbCommand)connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "select * from sometable";
                using (command)
                {
                    using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        foreach (DbDataRecord record in reader)
                        {
                            yield return new MyDynamicRecord(record);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

causes IndexOutOfRangeException

Using lower case `Record["dokumnr"]`
works OK.

In ASP.NET MVC4 Record["Dokumnr"] works.

How to force case-insensitive column name indexer in Mono 3.2.5 ?

Using Npgsql data provider in ASP.NET MVC4 application in Debian Linux.

Comment: How do you get the `IDataRecord` instance? If it is over the `DataTable` you can use `DataTable.CaseSensitive = false;`.

Comment: DataReader is used. I updated question and provided code for record retrieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tested, but give a try. Make use of `IDataRecord.GetOrdinal` method.

```
var columnOrdinal = Record.GetOrdinal("Dokumnr");
var value = Record[columnOrdinal];
```

Am not sure about your DB Provider, but [Sql will return treat case insensitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: GetOrdinal is slower. I'm using same data provider assembly (npgsql.dll) in Windows and in Linux. All names returned by GetName are in lowercase. In windows Record["Dokumnr"] also works. Now idea why Linux requires lowercase dokumnr. I fixed it using  Record[mycolumnname.ToLowerInvariant()] . Not sure is this best fix.